# Spring MVC Object Input

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

So if the bean were to have a non-primitive non-String type as a parameter that needed to be non-null, such as a Date or my own class, how would I put that in a .jsp? I'm not sure if the input parameters could take an object as a value.

I could always remove the non-null and have the request method set things up, but is there a way to set it in the form?

For a barebones example:

```
public class SpringBean{
    @NotNull
    private CustomObject obj;
    //getters/setters
}
```

Within jsp:

```
<sf:form modelAttribute="springBean" action="" method = "">
<sf:input type = "hidden" path = "obj" value = "${object_reference}"/>
/*insert rest of form*/
</sf:form>
```

Those are just examples of the jist of what I want to do, but am almost positive it won't work that way. So just wondering what I could do to emulate something like that.

Comment: N:B: Classes in Java are **always** in `PascalCase`, no exceptions.

Comment: Fixed it, don't know how I forgot that

Comment: Well, everything in HTML is a `String`, so you need some way to a) turn `${object_reference}` _into_ a `String` to put into the HTML and b) turn the incoming `String` back into the same `${object_reference}`. This is what Spring `Formatter` and the `WebDataBinder` do - see [this tutorial](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-validator-with-initbinder-webdatabinder-registercustomeditor-example).